# How can I cache dynamic CSS with HTTP headers?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, caching, dynamic-css

This is a direct duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999883/let-browsers-cache-my-dynamic-php-stylesheet), but the solution provided doesn't work.

As part of a WordPress plugin that I maintain, I am currently spitting out a dynamic CSS file using the following code:

```
public static function buildCustomCss() {
  if (1 == intval(get_query_var(self::$query_var))) {
     ob_start();
        global $css;
        $expires = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365; // cache for a year

        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Cache-Control: maxage=' . $expires);
        header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $expires) . ' GMT');
        header('Content-type: text/css');

        echo str_replace('&gt;', '>', esc_html($css));
     ob_end_flush();
     exit;
  }
}
```

The header values used match what is used in the cited question above, but both Chrome **AND** Firefox refuse to honor the cache request. I've tried multiple servers and each one spits back a `200` response every time. I'd hoped this would prove to be a better solution than just throwing the CSS into the main page, but if I can't get caching working then it's going to end up significantly worse.

The full list of request headers (Chrome):

```
Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:<cookie values>
DNT:1
Host:example.org
Referer:http://example.org/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36
```

The full list of response headers (*Edited to include latest headers tested, including `public` in both `pragma` and in `cache-control`*):

```
Cache-Control:no-transform,public,maxage=31536000
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:text/css; charset=UTF-8
Date:Sun, 30 Mar 2014 22:55:57 GMT
Expires:Mon, 30 Mar 2015 22:55:56 GMT
Pragma:public
Server:nginx
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a file to be cached by browsers, you should set the Cache-control header to public:

```
header('Cache-control: public');
```

Comment: It [shouldn't make a difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314174/difference-between-pragma-and-cache-control-headers), but I tried. No change.